# Talend - delete files older then X days

Tags: talend

How to delete contents of the folder older then x days in Talend job?

I have thought about retrieving that attribute from rFilesList (could not find) or passing unix command to a system (less preferable way as you have less control).

Thank you!

P.S. The issue solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a "tfilelist" coupled with a "tfileproperties".
The variable mtime or mtime_string can help you.

Here there is a page that explain a little bit (but it's in french so you can google trad if you want) :

[HERE](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1473732/logiciels/solutions-d-entreprise/business-intelligence/talend/developpement-jobs/parcours-d-dossier-recuperant-dates-modifications-fichiers/)

Answer (score 1):

My solution (based on a link above):
tFileList->iterate->tFileProperties (reads the file from previous step, ((String) globalMap.get ( "tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILEPATH")) )-> tMap has 2 outputs, based on mtime condition:

1. Files to delete: (TalendDate.getCurrentDate().getTime()-row3.mtime)/(24*60*60*1000) > 2
2. Files to keep: (TalendDate.getCurrentDate().getTime()-row3.mtime)/(24*60*60*1000) <=2

tFileDelete that deletes filesToDelete.filename

Answer (score 0):

Write a script to remove files over X days. and call the script from tSystem component : 
More about tSystem  :  https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide521EN/19.4+tSystem